# Python: how to get emails of Active Directory group members?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get all group members of Active Directory.

I have this code:

```
    from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, core

    server = Server(address, get_info=ALL)
    ad_conn = Connection(server, dn, password, auto_bind=True)
    members = []
    AD_GROUP_FILTER = '(&(objectClass=GROUP)(cn={group_name}))'
    ad_filter = AD_GROUP_FILTER.replace('{group_name}', group_name)
    result = ad_conn.search_s('OU details', ldap3.SCOPE_SUBTREE, ad_filter)
    if result:
        if len(result[0]) >= 2 and 'member' in result[0][1]:
            members_tmp = result[0][1]['member']
            for m in members_tmp:
                email = get_email_by_dn(m, ad_conn)
                if email:
                    members.append(email)
    return members
```

But I am getting an error

> 'Connection' object has no attribute 'search_s'

Comment: I'm not sure `search_s()` actually exists, do you mean 'synchronous' by '_s', in which case is the intent to make *synchronous* call ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`search()`](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/blob/master/docs/manual/source/searches.rst), specify the attributes you need (it seems you build 'email' from user dn but if it were present in the directory), and fix the arguments in function call (arg. order filter then scope, plus use the proper constant `SUBTREE`) :

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, core

server = Server(address, get_info=ALL)
ad_conn = Connection(server, dn, password, auto_bind=True)
members = []
AD_GROUP_FILTER = '(&(objectClass=GROUP)(cn={group_name}))'
ad_filter = AD_GROUP_FILTER.replace('{group_name}', group_name)    

ad_conn.search('OU details', ad_filter, ldap3.SUBTREE, attributes=['member', 'mail'])

if len(ad_conn.response): 
    # To grab data, you might prefer the following - or use ad_conn.entries : 
    for entry in ad_conn.response:
        print(entry['dn'], entry['attributes'])
```